# Mysql joining 2 query's in one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have 2 query's: the first one will retrieve the 5 users with the most delay and i am running inside the while loop a second query for retrieving the users username and name.
This is how it looks like:

```
select UserID, SUM(delay) as 'TOTdelay' FROM logboek WHERE date >= x AND date <= y GROUP BY UserID ORDER BY TOTdelay DESC LIMIT 5
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
   select Username, Name FROM users WHERE ID = $UserID LIMIT 1;
   echo $Username.' on the x place with a total delay of '.$TOTdelay;
}
```

How can i combine this 2 query's in to 1 so i don't have to run a query inside my while loop?

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Can you make a [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`INNER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

```
SELECT
  Username,
  Name,
  SUM(delay) AS `TOTdelay`
FROM
  logboek
INNER JOIN
  users ON UserId = users.ID
WHERE
  date BETWEEN 20130101 AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY
  UserID
ORDER BY
  TOTdelay DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select logboek.UserID, SUM(logboek.delay) as 'TOTdelay', users.Username, users.Name FROM logboek
LEFT JOIN users on (users.id = logboek.UserID)
 WHERE logboek.date >= x AND logboek.date <= y GROUP BY logboek.UserID ORDER BY TOTdelay DESC LIMIT 5
```